# In Python, is there any benefit of making a Thread and then join() over normal blocking process?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

In Python, is there any benefit of making a Thread and then join() over normal blocking process? For example, is this code:

```
def sleep():
    time.sleep(5)

print "start..."
t = threading.Thread(target=sleep)
t.start()
t.join()
print "end..."
```

any better than this:

```
def sleep():
    time.sleep(5)

print "start..."
sleep()
print "end..."
```

Is there any use-case or situation where one of it is better than the other?

Comment: None of these two is better because they both make no sense. Please illustrate your question with a real problem.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you join on a single thread there is not much benefit over a non-threaded approach.

The only thing I can think of is that you can specify a timeout for [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) to limit the time a computation may take. This is also possible without threads, but it would require you to modify the target function (to periodically check whether the time limit has been reached). Using a timeout for `join` is transparent to the underlying function.

Obviously, if you have more than one thread then joining one or more of them is drastically different than a single-threaded program, since the threads then work in parallel while only the main thread waits for the join to complete.

Comment: Calling `join(timeout)` will _not_ limit the time that a computation in a background thread may take.  It only will limit the amount of time that the calling thread is willing to wait for it.

Comment: @jameslarge you are correct and I was sloppy. Thanks for the clarification! After `join(timeout)` returns, one needs to call `is_alive` to check whether the thread is still running and (if it is) stop it -- ideally in a cooperative way [or forcefully](https://stackoverflow.com/q/323972/857390).